# When is $\int_{B(0,1)}\big(\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^k}|x-r_k|^{-\alpha}\big)^p\,dx <\infty$ true?

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

Denote $B(0,1)=\{x\in{\bf R}^n\mid |x|<1\}$ and let $\{r_k\}$ be a countable dense subset of $U:=B(0,1)$. Consider the following almost everywhere defined function on $U$:
$$
u(x):=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^k}|x-r_k|^{-\alpha},\quad (x\in U)
$$
where $\alpha>0$ is some fixed real number.

Here is my **question**:

> For what $\alpha$ do we have $L^p(U)$?

---

[Some thoughts] It is not difficult to show that for $\alpha p<n$, the map $x\mapsto |x-r_k|^{-\alpha}$ is in $L^p(U)$ for each $k$. Eventually, one wants
$$
\int_U\big(\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^k}|x-r_k|^{-\alpha}\big)^p\,dx
<\infty\tag{*}
$$
I find that things boil down to the following:

- Bound up to a constant the integral in ($*$) by $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k}\int_U|x-r_k|^{-\alpha p}\,dx$;
- Show that $\{a_k\}$ is a bounded set where
  $$
  a_k=\int_U|x-r_k|^{-\alpha p}\,dx.
  $$

Comment: Actually  $ |x-r_k|^{-\alpha}$ is in $L^p(U)$ iff  $\alpha p<n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in my comment, a necessary condition is that $\alpha p <n.$ Is this sufficient? Hint: By Jensen,

$$ \left (\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^k}|x-r_k|^{-\alpha} \right )^p \le  \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^k}(|x-r_k|^{-\alpha})^p.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In order to get ($*$), I think one needs also a bound on $a_k$? How would you do that?

Comment: Yes you do. Hint: $U\subset B(r_k,2)$ for all $k$.